# How to fetch data from Wikipedia table using dbpedia SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am able to perform queries like finding capital or currency of countries but having problem in fetching table data. I want to extract data from the tables from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Indian_states_and_union_territories_by_GDP) page. It's corresponding dbpedia page is [this](http://dbpedia.org/page/List_of_Indian_states_and_union_territories_by_GDP).

Now if you look at the dbpedia page, there is no relation for tabular data which I could query. What am I missing here?

Edit: There is a [project](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/ideas/idea/59/the-table-extractor/), which I guess, is under development at present. Is there any other way apart from scraping

Comment: Looks like this is not a fully solved problem yet. There are [papers written on it](http://aidanhogan.com/docs/ld4ie-2013.pdf) apart from the project you shared. If your requirement is one-off, you should be able to scrape the raw table data and maybe even create triples out of it (design of the relationships would be interesting - the states I already exist on DBPedia as entities)

Comment: Right, this is ongoing development and in general, ongoing research. In general one could use any csv2rdf tool and do it manually but doing it automatically isn't that simply. You could try out the current work in progress tool as part of the GSOC 2017: https://github.com/dbpedia/table-extractor But this has to be loaded into your own triple store then.

Answer (score 2):

This answer probably isn't going to help you right away but this is how I think it should work. 
Instead of "querying a table", think of it this way:
You are looking for all Indian states (each an entity on DBPedia), their GDP's and possibly other attributes. 
The GDP is (or ***should be*** ) an attribute of the state entity - the "List" page is simply a convenient aggregation and shouldn't serve as the master copy.

Something like:

```
select ?state ?gdp WHERE {
  ?state dbo:country dbr:India .
  ?state ?hasGDP ?gdp 
} 
ORDER by ?gdp
```

Sadly, the state pages on DBPedia don't currently have the `?hasDGP` property (on similar lines as they have the `dbo:populationTotal` property).

Because of these missing links, you are probably back to using scraping as an alternative.